# msysgit Git Bash ignores 1 entry in my PATH variable

Tags: windows, msysgit, git-bash

**The Problem**

When I enter the command `android` in the normal Windows command prompt, `android.bat` is launched from the a directory I included in the PATH-variable.

When I enter the same command in the msysgit Git Bash, the bash complains:
`sh.exe": android: command not found`

`android` is the only command that has this problem, all others work on both shells (the directory it is contained in is `android-sdk/tools` )
Working examples are node, npm, heroku.

**My environment**

This is what `echo $PATH` returns in Git Bash:

```
/c/Users/Tobias/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Users/Tobias/AppData/Local/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/cmd:/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/c/Python27:/c/Python34/:/c/Python34/Scripts:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Acronis/SnapAPI/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11/bin:/c/Ruby200-x64/bin:/c/Users/Tobias/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/Tobias/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/tools:/c/Users/Tobias/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools:.
```

This is what `echo %PATH%` returns in Windows CMD:

```
C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Local\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:   \Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Python27;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like msysgit can't access files inside `C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming`.
I fixed the issue by moving the directory directly in the `C:` drive.